# Servlet should have mapping and Cannot find servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to build a java web application using spring and hibernate and when I try to start it with tomcat, I'm getting an error regarding my web.xml. When I  look in the web.xml I get this:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        **<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name> <-------here I get Servlet should have mapping**
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        **<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name> <---Here I get cannot find servlet**
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The only mapping I have is

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/clients", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.api+json")
    public ClientsDto getClients() {
        List<Client> clientList = clientService.findAll();
        return new ClientsDto(clientList);
    }
}
```

The full error that I get when I try to run Tomcat is:

```
Connected to server
[2016-05-05 08:40:35,438] Artifact tryHW-web:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
05-May-2016 20:40:39.916 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = mpp Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "100" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
05-May-2016 20:40:39.917 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = mpp Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
05-May-2016 20:40:40.126 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2016-05-05T20:40:43,667 WARN  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]: nnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private shop.tryHW.core.repository.ClientRepository shop.tryHW.core.service.ClientServiceImpl.clientRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [shop.tryHW.core.repository.ClientRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} 
2016-05-05T20:40:43,729 ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]: ContextLoader                        - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private shop.tryHW.core.repository.ClientRepository shop.tryHW.core.service.ClientServiceImpl.clientRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [shop.tryHW.core.repository.ClientRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4732) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5194) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M4]
05-May-2016 20:40:43.741 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.8.0_31]
05-May-2016 20:40:43.743 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M4]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1480363463.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private shop.tryHW.core.repository.ClientRepository shop.tryHW.core.service.ClientServiceImpl.clientRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [shop.tryHW.core.repository.ClientRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [shop.tryHW.core.repository.ClientRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 59 more
[2016-05-05 08:40:43,811] Artifact tryHW-web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
05-May-2016 20:40:45.124 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4\webapps\manager
05-May-2016 20:40:45.448 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4\webapps\manager has finished in 323 ms
```

Here is the code for the ClientController:

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/clients", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.api+json")
    public ClientsDto getClients() {
        List<Client> clientList = clientService.findAll();
        return new ClientsDto(clientList);
    }

}
```

I have absolutely no idea what is asking from me or what the problem is.
Any ideas what is wrong? I don't understand what it is asking from me. I don't have a context xml or anything like that. I only have a web.xml

Is there any way that this is related to class instantiation or why would @Autowired not work?

Comment: You should post the error also

Comment: Added it. I can post more if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ClientRepository` has not been scanned into spring application context. Please make sure you have `@Repository` annotation on it or other bean annotation and could be scanned automatically by spring framework. Such as its base package on scanning path.

Comment: This is one of the problems. I forgot to add the proper annotations but it didn't fix it. It lead to SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc ' must have even number of URI's. And then it just throws the same bean errors again

Comment: Could you please post your full xml context settings?

Comment: Better together with the full error message or just publish your project into github, it will be useful for a good answer.

Comment: The problem was that my ClientRepository inherited the JpaRepository and I didn't have the JpaRepository Enabled with the proper annotation